# IAuthenticationFilter in SignalR 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, signalr

In my Web API 2 project I have JWT based authentication. The configuration is

```
  var config = new HttpConfiguration();
  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions {/**/});
  config.Filters.Add(new MyAuthenticationFilter());
  app.UseWebApi(config);
  app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
  app.MapSignalR();
```

`MyAuthenticationFilter` builds a custom principal based on an incoming JWT and attaches it to a request so that in my controller actions I can access it as `this.User`. Everything is working fine except the filter is ignored for SignalR requests:

```
public class MyHub : Hub {
    public override Task OnConnected() {
        // here Context.User is ClaimsPrincipal which contain a JWT from Authorization header
        // I expect it to be MyCustomPrincipal
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

Why `IAuthenticationFiltter` is ignored? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You cant use jwt on header with signalR. Send jwt in qs (query string) and add some customization on api that code below.

**App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           // SignalR Auth0 custom configuration.
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnRequestToken = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/signalr"))
                        {
                            string bearerToken = context.Request.Query.Get("token");
                            if (bearerToken != null)
                            {
                                string[] authorization = new string[] { "bearer " + bearerToken };
                                context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
                            }
                        }

                        return null;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

**and you use Authorize attribute on hub**

```
[Authorize]

 public class MyHub:Hub
```